# Use a class variable across inheritance in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

In Python, I want to define a top level class that can depend on a class variable. Then I want to be able to change that variable at the class level, for children of the class, but still inherit the functionality that uses that variable.

In general, my Parent class has some functions that depend on configuration variables. All my child classes use those same functions, but with different parameters. I would like to be able to change the parameters at the class level.

As the simplest example, here are two classes where the `Parent` defines functions in terms of `my_global`, then the `Child` attempts to change that variable (but fails)

```
class Parent():
    my_global = "parent"
    
    def _init_(self):
        pass

    def printmg(self):
        print(Parent.my_global)


class Child(Parent):
    my_global = "child"


my_parent = Parent()
my_parent.printmg()
my_child = Child()
my_child.printmg()
```

This outputs

```
parent
parent
```

While I would like it to output

```
parent
child
```

I don't wan't to keep the variables at the object level (i.e. `self.my_global = "child"`), or to rewrite the function for the child.

Comment: Change `print(Parent.my_global)` to `print(self.my_global)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line `print(Parent.my_global)` to `print(self.my_global)`.

The self operater represents the current class. So printing like this will work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need an instance method define `printmg` as `classmethod`:

```
@classmethod
def printmg(cls):
    print(cls.my_global)
```

Comment: Oh, great! Not what I was looking for but good to know that I can do that too!